# Error after installing brew formula in arm64 architecture

Tags: homebrew, apple-silicon

I'm trying to install `sundials` (a Nonlinear and differential/algebraic equations solver) using its `brew` formula on my M1-chip Macbook. I previously created a new installation under `/opt/homebrew/` to have a native Homebrew version:

```
$ brew config
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 3.3.16
ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew
HEAD: 2dc375acc2fe4e089d103171ec8fb06a87d83bb6
Last commit: 4 days ago
Core tap ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core
Core tap HEAD: ee1c1945110d475d441a5b7e11f58b83704e9e4b
Core tap last commit: 50 minutes ago
Core tap branch: master
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /opt/homebrew
HOMEBREW_CASK_OPTS: []
HOMEBREW_CORE_GIT_REMOTE: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core
HOMEBREW_DISPLAY: /private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.Xs1aY002mO/org.macosforge.xquartz:0
HOMEBREW_MAKE_JOBS: 10
Homebrew Ruby: 2.6.8 => /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby
CPU: 10-core 64-bit arm_firestorm_icestorm
Clang: 13.0.0 build 1300
Git: 2.32.0 => /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/git
Curl: 7.77.0 => /usr/bin/curl
macOS: 12.2.1-arm64
CLT: 13.2.0.0.1.1638488800
Xcode: 13.2.1
Rosetta 2: false
```

After installing `sundials`, I tried to run a simple C++ (`g++` is the compiler) code but I got the following error:

```
$ g++ user-data.cpp -o main
user-data.cpp:9:10: fatal error: 'cvode/cvode.h' file not found
#include <cvode/cvode.h> // prototypes for CVODE fcts., consts.
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

Then, I tried this other option:

```
$ g++ -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/sundials/5.8.0/include/ user-data.cpp -o main
user-data.cpp:96:8: warning: 'SUNSPGMR' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  LS = SUNSPGMR(y, 0, 0);
       ^
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/sundials/5.8.0/include/sunlinsol/sunlinsol_spgmr.h:99:1: note: 'SUNSPGMR' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
SUNDIALS_DEPRECATED_EXPORT SUNLinearSolver SUNSPGMR(N_Vector y, int pretype, int maxl);
^
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/sundials/5.8.0/include/sundials/sundials_export.h:29:54: note: expanded from macro 'SUNDIALS_DEPRECATED_EXPORT'
#  define SUNDIALS_DEPRECATED_EXPORT SUNDIALS_EXPORT SUNDIALS_DEPRECATED
                                                     ^
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/sundials/5.8.0/include/sundials/sundials_export.h:25:47: note: expanded from macro 'SUNDIALS_DEPRECATED'
#  define SUNDIALS_DEPRECATED __attribute__ ((__deprecated__))
                                              ^
1 warning generated.
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_CVSpilsSetJacTimes", referenced from:
      _main in user-data-138c42.o
  "_CVSpilsSetLinearSolver", referenced from:
      _main in user-data-138c42.o
  "_CVode", referenced from:
      _main in user-data-138c42.o
  "_CVodeCreate", referenced from:
      _main in user-data-138c42.o
  "_CVodeFree", referenced from:
      _main in user-data-138c42.o
  "_CVodeInit", referenced from:
      _main in user-data-138c42.o
  "_CVodeSStolerances", referenced from:
      _main in user-data-138c42.o
  "_CVodeSetUserData", referenced from:
      _main in user-data-138c42.o
  "_N_VDestroy", referenced from:
      _main in user-data-138c42.o
  "_N_VGetArrayPointer", referenced from:
      f(double, _generic_N_Vector*, _generic_N_Vector*, void*) in user-data-138c42.o
      jtv(_generic_N_Vector*, _generic_N_Vector*, double, _generic_N_Vector*, _generic_N_Vector*, void*, _generic_N_Vector*) in user-data-138c42.o
  "_N_VNew_Serial", referenced from:
      _main in user-data-138c42.o
  "_N_VPrint_Serial", referenced from:
      _main in user-data-138c42.o
  "_SUNLinSolFree", referenced from:
      _main in user-data-138c42.o
  "_SUNSPGMR", referenced from:
      _main in user-data-138c42.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

For some reason, my links are still *looking* for the x86_64 version of the files. It seems my machine is a mess right now, so I would highly appreciate any suggestions on how to fix this problem.

Comment: What is g++. It is ot a good idea to use that on a command line

Comment: `g++` is a C++ compiler, thank you!

Comment: Yes but which version and why yuse that on macOS where the one supplied by Apple is clang?

Comment: It is just a shortcut. I'm actually using clang, as you can notice here: `g++ --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin21.3.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you simply misunderstood the message given to you by your linker. It is not so that it is looking for x86_64 versions of files - it is telling you plainly that it did not find arm64 versions of those symbols.

That is because you forgot to actually link the sundials library in. So there's no sundial symbols at all - for any architecture.

You can link in the library by using the `-l` argument for g++. I.e. change your command to something like this:

```
g++ -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/sundials/5.8.0/include/ user-data.cpp -o main -lsundials_cvodes
```

The library might be called something slightly different, it could also be that you want `-lsundials_nvecserial`, `-lsundials_cvode` or similar, depending on what you're trying to do.

You might need to link multiple libraries depending on your own source code. Check the list of libraries installed in the sundials folder for "inspiration".

Depending on your setup, you might need to let the compiler know where to find the library using the `-L` argument. For example:

```
g++ -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/sundials/5.8.0/include/ user-data.cpp -o main -lsundials -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/sundials/5.8.0/lib
```

or something similar depending on your specific setup.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what was going on. I appreciate it.